# Get memory usage of open file descriptors

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, file-descriptor

I know how to find number of files currently open using - `lsof | wc -l` or for a particular PID or for an user.

Is it possible to list the corresponding PID's and how many file descriptors and memory are they using ?

I hope I made it clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [man ps](https://www.petefreitag.com/tools/man-pages/ps.html):

```
rss   resident set size
size      memory size in kilobytes
```

Just call `ps ax -o pid,rss,size` to get processes with resident size and memory size.  As for file descriptors, we can count number of files in `/proc/<PID>/fd/*` directory for each process:

```
ps -A -opid | sudo xargs -n1 -I{} /bin/bash -c 'echo {} $(ls /proc/{}/fd | wc -l);'
```

Comment: Just want to ask about file descriptors. Does it use memory?

Comment: @jalil what uses memory? Everything (every abstract thing) on a PC uses memory.